# Z-module homomorphisms from nZ to Z[1/2]/Z

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules

I want to find a description of $\text{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(n\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}[1/2]/\mathbb{Z})$. Since they are $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, it is enough to just look at group homomorphisms from the former to the latter. Here's what I have tried so far:

We can write $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]/\mathbb{Z} = \{ \frac{m}{2^a} ; m \ \text{odd}, a \geq 0 \}$. Furthermore, $n\mathbb{Z}$ is a cyclic group with only one generator $n$, so to define a homomorphism $\phi: n\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}[1/2]/\mathbb{Z}$, it is enough to just specify a value of $\phi$ at $n$. Furthermore, I believe $n$ can be sent to anything since it has infinite order, i.e. $\phi(n)$ can be $\frac{m}{2^a}$ for any odd $m$ and $a \geq 0$. Is this correct? If I am correct, then does this just mean $\text{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(n\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}[1/2]/\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One should add that $n \mathbb Z$ isn't a group, because it doesn't have an identity.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that $\frac{m}{2^a}$ does not have infinite order. Instead, if $m$ is odd, it has order $2^a$; more generally, if $m$ is not required to be odd, it has order $2^{a-b}$, where $m = 2^b n$ and $\gcd(n,2)=1$.

Otherwise, you are completely right in asserting that an arbitrary element defines a morphism. Yet, then of course
$$
\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(n\mathbb Z, \mathbb Z[1/2]/\mathbb Z) \cong \mathbb Z[1/2]/\mathbb Z
$$
by the definition of addition of morphisms (pointwise).

Comment: I understand that $\frac{m}{2^a}$ has finite order - but what about, for example, the morphism $n \mapsto \frac{1}{2}$? Isn't this a nontrivial morphism (with kernel $2n\mathbb{Z}$)?

Comment: So sorry, I made a silly mistake there. The only morphism *in the other direction* would be the zero morphism.

Comment: @dacian98 I believe the current answer is correct.

Comment: ahh I see - so the idea is that we identify each morphism with its value at $n$, and this yields the isomorphism $\text{Hom}_\mathbb{Z} (n\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}[1/2]/\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}[1/2]/\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Remember that *as a $\Bbb Z$-module*, $n\Bbb Z$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$: an infinite cyclic group. So the group of homomorphisms with it as domain are isomorphic to the codomain, whatever it is.